# After migration customers can't log using m1 password

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I migrated the M1EE 1.12.0.2 to M2EE 2.1.5 using the data migration tool provide by Magento. Now after migration the existing customer unable to login and magento 2 is throwing an error "Invalid login".

Comment: data migration tool is not 100% trust worthy.

Comment: @PavanKumar Is there any other way to migrate the customer password from M1 to M2

Answer (score 1):

I got another solution and very quick and easy

Just Empty the table (TRUNCATE) " customer_entity_varchar "

100% sure login old customer in New magento 2

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this is old, but it solved my customers login issue in Magento 2.3.4 after a migration. Be careful with the attributes that are migrated!! They might cause this type of login issues!

Answer (score 0):

#### You must create a new admin user from the terminal, see below:

this code run in the terminal on root project.

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="admin88" --admin-password="admin88123" --admin-email="email@domain.com" --admin-firstname="FirstName" --admin-lastname="LastName"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't login using magento 1 password because Magento 1 and Magento 2 have their own hash password method. You need to set a password module.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the exact same issues as you but I managed to fix my customer passwords by using this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294312/46258

P.S. You will need to clear out generated/ and rebuild. I'm using:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/composer_home/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```