# Customer password not working after migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento-1.6, password, data-migration-tool

I have migrated only customers from **Magento 1.6.2.0 to Magento 2.2.3** and customers migrated successfully and listed properly in the admin section.

But when I try to login with the Magento 1 password I am not able to login.

So as I check in database the old passwords are stored differently than the Magento 2 passwords.

Here's a screenshot of the database table **"customer_entity"**:

[image]

Basically I have found that when customer created from Magento 2 frontend there is a larger string after the first colon `:` and migrated passwords have only two character after the colon `:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The data migration tool takes advantage of such backward compatibility in Magento to automatically migrate Customer password from Magento 1 to Magento 2. So your customers can use their `md5()` based password without the need to reset their passwords after migration. "
Meaning they can log in with their md5 password ? I tried, to no avail.

Comment: Thanks, This command works for me  php -f bin/magento customer:hash:upgrade

Comment: I have done the above methods and that does not work for me. Any other suggestion? Iam using magento 2.2.4 and upgrade is from 1.9.2.4

Comment: @DivyaMuralidharan is there any error you get when you perform hash:upgrade command in SSH?

Comment: @Jalpesh Yes. I got this error  " [ReflectionException]                                           
  Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist"

Comment: @DivyaMuralidharan do you have any custom attribute in magento 1.9.2.4 which type is datetime??

Comment: @DivyaMuralidharan if possible please add error screenshot here.

Comment: @DivyaMuralidharan Please create new question with screenshot and what you tried.

Comment: I have done the above methods and that does not work for me. I am using Magento 2.2.5.

Comment: @PrashantPatel ,I have same issue and tried all things but not working,If you got any solution please let me know.Same If I got  will let you know.

Comment: @lalitmohan,I have tried your suggestions but not working.If you have any idea Please let me know.

Comment: @akgola Can you please create new question and also mention what have you tried and what problem are you facing right now?? . like I consider you successfully migrate data (user) without any error .

Comment: @lalitmohan,please check link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238127/24878

Comment: Hello @lalitmohan,did you checked url in earlier comment?

Comment: @akgola Yes I checked. I will post possible solutions on post.

Comment: I am getting this error. Please help ->  Notice: Undefined index: 0:1 in E:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 189

Answer (score 3):

After migrating database from magento1 to magento2, customer login problem occurs, to solve that problem just go to a file name encryptor.php in the vendor folder (Path is below)
vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php
and change isValidHash() function like below.

```
        public function isValidHash($password, $hash)
       { 
          try { 

            $this->explodePasswordHash($hash);

           foreach ($this->getPasswordVersion() as $hashVersion) {

            if ($hashVersion == '0') {

                $recreated = current(explode(':', $hash));

            }else if ($hashVersion === self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13) {
                $recreated = $this->getArgonHash($password, $this->getPasswordSalt());
            } else {

                $recreated = $this->generateSimpleHash($this->getPasswordSalt() . $password, $hashVersion);
            }

            $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
            error_log('password changing technique ======');
            error_log(print_r($recreated,true));
            error_log(print_r($hash,true));
        }
    } catch (\RuntimeException $exception) {
        //Hash is not a password hash.
        $recreated = $this->hash($password);
    }

    return Security::compareStrings(
        $recreated,
        $hash
    );
}
```

the above change wont cause any issue because once user login with above method, magento2 will change the password hash to its proper password format and you can see difference in customer_entity table in magento2 database.

Comment: Well, this works, but it's a very bad practice to edit files in /vendor folder

Comment: Srokatonie I appreciate your comment but there is no other option available till now and its a quick fix if you want to try.

Comment: It showing error like Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13' vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 215

Comment: Kowsigan Atsayam  which version of magento you are using actually it worked with magento 2.3 but stiil please check for this line in your file
 public const HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13 = 2;
if it is not present please add it its a constant or else please copy your Encryptor.php file here let me check.

Comment: You, my man; have saved a life today. Mobsters wanted to hang me for not gettign the site up today but now, because of your extreme knowledge and understanding I may live to fight another day.

Comment: Am I crazy, or you basically allowing to login with any password as long as its first log in after migration and email is matching? With `$recreated = current(explode(':', $hash));` you are saying compare stored hash to stored hash, ignore password given by user...

Answer (score 1):

I have created my own extension for customer migration and that was work perfectly with my Magento version: 2.2.4.

**My logic:** Taking Magento1 password and appending ":0" before inserting into Magento2 customer table.

Let me know if you need more info for same, I am happy to help the community!

Comment: Is it possible you can share your migration extension and/or logic?

Comment: please send the link of your extension

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate [Shubanshu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/84016/shubhanshu)'s answer, but as [srokatonie](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/44597/srokatonie) stated below it you should never edit files directly in vendor folder.

Instead, [create a custom module](https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/) with an `app/code/{CustomModuleVendor}/{CustomModuleNamespace}/etc/di.xml` file in it with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor" type="{CustomModuleVendor}\{CustomModuleNamespace}\Enrcyption\Encryptor" />
</config>
```

And the `app/code/{CustomModuleVendor}/{CustomModuleNamespace}/Encryption/Encryptor.php`file:

```
<?php
namespace {CustomModuleVendor}\{CustomModuleNamespace}\Encryption;

class Encryptor extends \Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor {
    const HASH_VERSION_LATEST = "1";

    protected $passwordHashMap = [
        self::PASSWORD_HASH => '',
        self::PASSWORD_SALT => '',
        self::PASSWORD_VERSION => self::HASH_VERSION_LATEST
    ];

    private $hashVersionMap = [
        self::HASH_VERSION_MD5 => 'md5',
        self::HASH_VERSION_SHA256 => 'sha256',
        self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13 => 'md5'
    ];

   /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isValidHash($password, $hash)
    {
        try {
   
            $this->explodePasswordHash($hash);

            foreach ($this->getPasswordVersion() as $hashVersion) {

                if ($hashVersion == '0') {

                    $recreated = current(explode(':', $hash));

                }else if ($hashVersion === self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13) {
                    $recreated = $this->getArgonHash($password, $this->getPasswordSalt());
                } else {

                    $recreated = $this->generateSimpleHash($this->getPasswordSalt() . $password, $hashVersion);
                }

                $hash = $this->getPasswordHash();
                error_log('password changing technique ======');
                error_log(print_r($recreated,true));
                error_log(print_r($hash,true));
            }
        } catch (\RuntimeException $exception) {
            //Hash is not a password hash.
            $recreated = $this->hash($password);
        }

        return Security::compareStrings(
            $recreated,
            $hash
        );
    }
```

Make sure to replace all occurences of {CustomModuleVendor} {CustomModuleNamespace} with your module vendor and namespace.

This will use your class intance instead of the core one without changing vendor files (which would be lost when you update your magento framework).

More about using di.xml [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html)

Comment: And with that first login to migrated account can be done with any password, as password here is never checked. A bit unsecure I would say.