# Still Not able to login in Admin

Tags: magento2

I have used the admin account one year before, now i have forgot the user credentials, then i run the following queries on the admin_user table in magneto2 db

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = 'admin' WHERE username = 'admin';
```

and **query was successful**

and unlocked the account also using following -

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock admin
```

and got message that **The user account "admin" has been unlocked**

then i removed the cache using

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and removed unwanted sessions from `'admin_user_sessions'` table

Now when i try to login in localhost/magneto2/admin ->

Username - admin
Password - admin

I am getting error ***You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled.***

What may be the error, Please help i am trying to login since 4-5 hours.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot update a plain password directly in sql. Magento stores passwords in encrypted format

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if any issue will generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your database and execute this query :

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxYourNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

It will useful to reset your password and you can login by new password.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your password or username is wrong, or maybe there is a fault at your account , try create your own admin user by using this command line, and change your old admin credential:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user USERNAME --admin-password PASSWORD --admin-email TEST@EMAIL.COM --admin-firstname FIRSTNAME --admin-lastname LASTNAME
```

Comment: This worked for me and used the new account to reset the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try `UPDATE admin_user SET 'password' = SHA2('yourpswhere', 256) WHERE 'username'='admin';` this sql query in your database table. Hope it works.Credit : @Suresh Chikani. I think you have to read this link for know about why directly using MD5 in sql query password not set in Magento2. [Customer password not working after migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223588/customer-password-not-working-after-migration-from-magento-1-to-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

You should not update plain password in MySql, Magento stores passwords in encrypted format.

Try Below in your phpMyAdmin

```
SET @salt = MD5(UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2(@salt,'YourNewPassword', 256), ':',@salt,':1') WHERE username = 'admin';
```

Instead of created salt you can use Magento crypto key saved in this file

> app\etc\env.php

```
array (
    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', //cryptograp...
  ),
```