# M2 Import customers with API with hashed passwords?

Tags: magento2, customer, api, password

I can import customers with the API using `/rest/all/V1/customers` endpoint. I can also supply a `password`.

But **is it possible to import a customer with a hashed password with the M2 API?** If possible, how would I do that? To be clear, I just want to supply a hashed password in the request. It's coming from Magento 1 and is MD5 hashed (which M2 supports).

I tried `password_hash` (named like the field in the table) instead, but that doesn't work. The field stays NULL.

**TL:DR**

How can I import customers with hashed passwords with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this `/rest/default/V1/customers/me` - it does indeed save the new customer entity and the set password_hash, but the customer is unable to login afterwards. So i'm missing something, but the method looks promising.

---

***LE:*** As Akif suggested, I needed to add the `:0` at the end of the M1 hash.

Comment: hey @Akif, did you try this?

Comment: No not yet. What is the difference with this endpoint and the one in my question? To fix your issue regarding not working of hashes. If the hash is coming from Magento 1 just add `:0` to the end of the string. This will make it work since M2 its backwards compatible. See also https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259638/5827

Comment: I don't have an m1 pass to try this out (i tried to emulate it, unsuccessfully, it seems), but thought you might and see if suits your needs. it's different from your mentioned endpoint as you provide the password in the 'password' property of the payload, and I provide the 'passwordHash' in mine which will fill in the `password_hash` field from the customers entity table.

Comment: I am getting an error on this route. `The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.`.  The "normal" route without the `/me` part does still work. The integration user has all resources allowed. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like something to do with the permissions of the user/ integration. in my tests, i used postman with a bearer token obtained by calling `{{magento_api_url}}/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token?username={{admin_username}}&password={{admin_password}}`. not sure how you call the api

Comment: Hmm, I tried to obtain a token that way, and I got further a bit in the process. But now I get the following error. `Message: Property "PasswordHash" does not have accessor method "getPasswordHash" in class "Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface"`. I tried both `password_has` as `passwordHash` (since Swagger has an example as the latter one). Which version of M2 are you on? I am testing with 2.3.6.

Comment: i tried on 2.4.1, but the documentation says it's available on 2.3.6 too https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.6-admin/#operation/customerCustomerRepositoryV1SavePut

Comment: Yes, /swagger is listing it too. I think I found the problem. I had the hash inside the customer object. It should have been outside it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yep, that happened to me as well when i first tried it :D :D glad you sorted this out. please consider marking this this topic as solved if you found the solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to add extra code or plugins to support the MD5 hash in Magento 2.

If you want to import the passwords  directly you just have to add ":0" after the raw password from Magento 1.

Magento 2 supports multiple versions to hash the password. Version 0 is MD5, which is used by Magento 1.

The passwords in Magento 2 are formatted as:
{password hash}:{salt}:{hash version}

The passwords in Magento 1 are formatted as:
{password hash}:{salt}

Comment: Thanks for your answer I figured that out already. But this was not the question. The questions is how to import the hash trough the API.

Comment: Create your own API endpoint and do as above

Comment: its seems `/V1/customers/me` supports sending the hash along to insert it as Diana pointed out. No need to make a custom endpoint

Comment: @Akif, did work as expected? if so, please consider marking the proper answer as solution. would be great to let me know if it indeed suits the needs for an m1 to m2 customer migration via API and i will edit my answer accordingly so there is no doubt it does what it's supposed to.